# How to pass file in my GraphQL query for my Integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, graphql, apollo, junit5

So I'm trying to write an Integration test for my query that accepts a file (Upload scalar) from Apollo.

```
    @Test
    void imageFromSimilarImage() throws IOException {
        when(imageService.findBySimilarImage(/*** some-file ***/)).thenReturn(TEST_IMAGE_LIST);

        GraphQLResponse response = graphQLTestTemplate.postForResource("graphql/image-from-similar-image.graphql");

        assertThat(response.isOk()).isTrue();
        assertThat(response.getList("$.data.imageFromSimilarImage", Image.class)).contains(TEST_IMAGE_A);
    }
```

my image-from-similar-image.graphql file:

```
query {
    imageFromSimilarImage(file: /*** "some-file-content" ***/) {
        url
        cloudinaryId
        tags {
            value
        }
    }
}
```

My original graphql schema, image.graphql file, if needed...

```
scalar Upload

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}

type Image {
    id: ID!
    cloudinaryId: String!
    url: String!
    tags: [Tag]
}

type Tag {
    id: ID!
    value: String!
    image: Image!
}

type Query {
    imageFromTag(tags : [String!]!): [Image]
    imageFromSimilarImage(file: Upload!): [Image]
    allImages : [Image]
}

type Mutation {
    createImage(files: [Upload!]!) : [Image]
}
```

Any ideas? I've browsed around for this , however couldn't find anything, with Junit ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the signature of my query `imageFromSimilarImage` to the following:

```
imageFromSimilarImage(files: [Upload!]!) : [Image]
```

Basically what this allowed me to do, is to pass an empty array in my test graphql file,

```
query {
    imageFromSimilarImage(file: []) {
        url
        cloudinaryId
        tags {
            value
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in my test case:

```
@Test
void imageFromSimilarImage() throws IOException {
    when(imageService.findBySimilarImage(anyList())).thenReturn(TEST_IMAGE_LIST);

    GraphQLResponse response = graphQLTestTemplate.postForResource("graphql/image-from-similar-image.graphql");

    assertThat(response.isOk()).isTrue();
    assertThat(response.getList("$.data.imageFromSimilarImage", Image.class)).contains(TEST_IMAGE_A);
}
```

However, this does change the behavior of the query, as in it accepts Multiple files, now instead of just one, although in my case this does not affect anything.
Just keep this in mind, and make sure it is acceptable in your case as well.